# Is there a TOEFL-like exam for Italian and French languages?

Tags: exams, certifications

I'm looking for TOEFL-like certificates for Italian and French. Are there any?

Comment: just googling would give u a pretty accurate idea

Answer (score 4):

In addition to those listed in the other answer, here are a few more:

For **French**:

- the [Test de Connaissance du Français (TCF)](http://www.fiaf.org/frenchclasses/frenchexam-tcf.shtml) is an certification that grades candidates on the CEFR scale from A1 to C2. Each certificate awarded is valid for 2 years.
- several other French proficiency certifications can be found on the website of the [French Institute](http://www.fiaf.org/frenchclasses/frenchexams.shtml).

For **Italian**:

- the [Italian Language Diplomas "Firenze"](http://www.acad.it/en/) are a set of certifications that correspond to the CEFR scale from A1 to C2. They are offered by the [Accademia Italiana di Lingua (AIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accademia_Italiana_di_Lingua).

Answer (score 2):

For **French**, two important certificates are DELF and DALF:

- the [Diplôme d'études en langue française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d%27%C3%A9tudes_en_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) (DELF) is a set of certificates for CEFR levels A1 – B2.
- the [Diplôme approfondi de langue française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_approfondi_de_langue_fran%C3%A7aise) (DALF) is a set of certificates for CEFR levels C1 and C2.

In addition to DELF for the general public, there are also versions of the certificate for school children and for "professionals". See the website of the [French ministry of education](http://www.ciep.fr/en/delf-dalf).

The Institut français, which is represented in many countries, offers exam preparation courses for DELF and DALF, and sometimes also for other certificates, such as [TCF](https://www.institut-francais.org.uk/french-courses/exams/tcf/) (Test de Connaissance du Français) and [DAEFLE](https://www.institut-francais.org.uk/french-courses/exams/daefle/) (Diplôme d’aptitude à l’enseignement du français langue étrangère).
See for example the website of the [Institut français Royaume-Uni](https://www.institut-francais.org.uk/french-courses/exams/exam-preparation-revision/).

For **Italian**, there are certificates such as

- [Certification of Italian as a Foreign Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_of_Italian_as_a_Foreign_Language) (Certificazione di Italiano come Lingua Straniera or CILS), a certificate offered by the Foreigners University of Siena, covering the CEFR levels B1 – C2.
- the [Progetto Lingua Italiana Dante Alighieri (PLIDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLIDA) ("Dante Alighieri Society Diplomas") is a series of tests and certificates for each of the six CEFR levels (A1 – C2).
- the [Certificato di Conoscenza della Lingua Italiana (CELI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CELI) ("Certificate of Knowledge of the Italian Language") has tests for three levels, but I don't know how they map to CEFR levels.

Preparation courses for PLIDA are offered by schools that are part of the Dante Alighieri Society; see for example the information provided by the [Società Dante Alighieri in Milan](http://www.societadantealighieri.org/en/plida).

For CILS, it is also worth checking out the websites of the schools that are part of the [Network of Italian Cultural Institutes](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/politica_estera/cultura/reteiic.html) (which are supported by the Italian Ministry of Foreign Affairs and International Cooperation). For example, the [Istituto Italiano di Cultura di Stoccarda](http://www.iicstoccarda.esteri.it/iic_stoccarda/de/imparare_italiano/i_corsi_di_lingua/i-corsi-di-lingua.html) (in Stuttgart, Germany), is a certified exam centre for CILS.